# Django / DRF - Get field of a related model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

everyone.
What I want is get field of a related model by serializer.
I have 2 models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text    



class Test(models.Model):
    test_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    question = models.ManyToManyField(Question, related_name='tests')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.test_name
```

Why I've used ManyToManyField?
Because I've followed here:
https://medium.com/django-rest/lets-build-a-basic-product-review-backend-with-drf-part-1-652dd9b95485

Now I can do smth like:
[image]

But I want get question_text in response.
What I tried:

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    question_text = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source="question.question_text")
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ['pk', 'test_name', 'pub_date', 'question_text']
        expandable_fields = {
 'question': (QuestionSerializer, {'many': True})
}
```

But it returned:

[image]

I understand, that problem might be in DB relations, but I can't get it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nested serializer:

```py
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['question_text']

class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    question = QuestionSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ['pk', 'test_name', 'pub_date', 'question']
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this I don't know which one is better but this is them
1- create a separate Serializer for question and assgin related_name in models.py to him

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = "__all__"




class TestSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    tests = QuestionSerializer(many=True) ## related_name
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ['pk', 'test_name', 'pub_date', 'tests']
```

2 - using serializers.SerializerMethodField()

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        question = serializers.SerializerMethodField() 
        class Meta:
            model = Test
            fields = ['pk', 'test_name', 'pub_date', 'question']
        def get_question(self, obj):
            question = obj.tests.all()
            serilaizer = QuestionSerializer(question, many=True)
            return serilaizer.data
```